# How can I use the Excel Online Flow connector to load a file from Azure File Storage?

Tags: azure, azure-storage, power-automate, azure-storage-files

We have a requirement to import files from Azure File Storage that are refreshed on a daily basis i.e the names and locations remain constant. We are using Microsoft Flow to load and process these files.

During the build phase, for convenience developers stored the sample file on One Drive and used the Excel Online (Business) connector to read the file (this was until the storage became available).

Now we are trying to replace the One Drive source with Azure File Storage and there seems to be no direct way of doing this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is currently no support for Azure File Storage event-based triggers in Flow or Logic Apps.  That is not to say there is no support for Azure File Storage at all though.

What you can do however is list files in Azure File Storage.  This gives you the ability to create a workflow which can act upon the presence of files.  In order to use Azure File Storage actions, you either need to use a Logic App or Flow Premium.

A workaround would involve engineering your process such that files would be placed in to a designated folder for processing.  Once your workflow has been executed the files should be deleted or archived by moving them to a different folder out of scope of the workflow.

You could use a schedule trigger to automate the workflows execution; a manual trigger; or an HTTP trigger, for which you could call using an Azure Automation Runbook to automate the invocation, which itself can be scheduled.

Comment: I thought that might be the case. Thank you for your response, I will look into implementing a copy process to One Drive (or some accessible location) as you have described.